# Getting 2 entities for 1 word in luis.ai

Tags: c#, azure-language-understanding

I'm using `LUIS` and I have two entities:

- a list entity
- a simple entity.

When I query`LUIS` that matches both in one word I get both entities.

I only want the simple entity but it matches the list entity as well because there is an inner string that matches a word in the synonyms list of the list entity.
Is there a way to only get the entity that matches the whole word and not just part of it.

[image: Image of LuisResult]

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't a way to do that. However in your code, you can filter base on your entity `Type` and only focus in the one with the value "Pets".

Comment: If I try to enter the same utterance in the "Train & Test" interface on luis.ai website. I get only 1 entity back. So why not in the real world application.
It seems strange to me that the train interface gives back different responses than when using the Api.

Comment: Have you published the app?

Comment: Luis has completely changed the structure of their website (luis.ai).
And now the test interface does give back the same things as the api does when it is called outside of the luis.ai website.